# ask for a lightweithg jquery based chart lib

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I have to build some chart in my page,I use extjs chart now,but I found it is rather **heavy**...

Through the google,there some jquery based lib,but I have no idea which is better,and it seems test them one by one is not a good idea,so I ask you guys if you have any experiences?

I just care the following points:

> 1)support drawing chart based json
>   data.
>
> 2)reload chart when data refreshed.
>
> 3)easily and readable coding
>
> 4)the less thrid-part lib needed,the
>   better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)
ticks all your boxes. I have been using it, seems pretty slick to me.

Flot supports column-line combined chart, thats actually why I used it, see [here](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/graph-types.html) and [here](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/) for a more comprehensive list of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/), which does most of the things you require.

Here's a good list of charting libraries for jQuery:

http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/02/6-jquery-chart-plugins-reviewed/

Comment: Hi,does the flot support column-line combined chart?